# Creating an F5 Pool And Assign Multiple Health Monitors To It

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip

Say I create two nodes `SERVER1` and `SERVER2`

```
create ltm node SERVER1 description SERVER1 address 10.1.1.1%200
create ltm node SERVER2 description SERVER2 address 10.1.1.2%200
```

After I added the nodes I wanted to create a pool and assign it multiple Health Monitors instead of just a single one. In my script I have something like this

```
create ltm pool some_pool_1 members add { SERVER1:0 SERVER2:0 } monitor health_monitor_1 health_monitor_2 monitor_3 health_monitor_4 health_monitor_5
```

This will only assign this `health_monitor_1` before throwing a `Syntax Error: "health_monitor_2" unknown property`. When I go into `health_monitor_1` I can see `SERVER1` and `SERVER2` but when I go into any of the other Health Monitors I do not see the nodes `SERVER1` and `SERVER2`in there. I have to go into the Pool and manually assign it the other Health Monitors. Can someone help me change my script `create ltm pool some_pool_1 members add { SERVER1:0 SERVER2:0 } monitor health_monitor_1 health_monitor_2 monitor_3 health_monitor_4 health_monitor_5` to be able to assign multiple health monitors to my pool?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to attach multiple monitors to the pool you are creating, you need to put them in parentheses:

```
create ltm pool p1 members add { 10.1.1.1:80 10.1.1.2:80 } monitor "http https"
```

or, if you want to have a minimum number of two monitors working:

```
create ltm pool p1 members add { 10.1.1.1:80 10.1.1.2:80 } monitor min 2 of { tcp http https }
```